# How to create a map of unique object keys and objects in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried the following:

```
class Obj{
public:
    int id;
    static int count;
    static map<int, Obj> ObjMap;

    Obj(){
        id = count++;
        ObjMap[id] = *this;
    }
};
int Obj::count = 0;
map<int, Obj> Obj::ObjMap;
```

but when i try to create an object inside main() the program terminates automaticaclly.

Comment: `ObjMap[id]` creates default `Obj` which creates default `Obj`, which .. (infinite loop)

Answer (score 3):

`std::map::operator[]` is a little exotic and holds some surprises. It is neither just element access nor just to insert elements (that would be `at()` or `insert` resp.). What `operator[]` actually does is: If no element with provided key is found it creates one with default constructed mapped value and then it returns a reference to that element.

As mentioned in a comment, you have an infinite loop, because before calling `[id]` there was no element with that key, hence the default constructor is called again and again and again.

To insert an element in a map use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

```
ObjMap.insert({id,*this});
```

Also you do not need to keep track of `count` manually. Bookkeeping of a containers size seperate from the container is error prone. Your `count` is always equal to `ObjMap.size()`, hence you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is holding object by value. This means it is storing copies of the objects:

When you add an object to the map in the constructor of Obj, this adds a new instance of Obj to the map; Within the constructor of this new instance, it is also added to the map, which creates a new instance --- and the loop goes on and on forever.

The solution requires:

- storing addresses to objects in the map:

  ```
  static map<int, Obj*> ObjMap;
  ```

  constructor implementation:

  ```
  Obj() {
    id = count++;
    ObjMap[id] = this;
  }
  ```
- adding an implementation of the copy constructor and assignment operator:

  these would have their own id (copy constructor also increments the count) and copying an existing object would not copy the id - only any other values the object has. The copy constructor would have to register itself in the map as well.
- adding move constructor and copy from temporary: these would (I assume) reuse an id, and replace the original in the map?.
- adding a destructor, which would remove objects from the map. Otherwise, when an object goes out of scope, you will be left with invalid addresses in your map.